# Evaluating all the notebook calling a package doesn't work whereas evaluating the package "manually", then run the notebook

Tags: evaluation, packages

I have put all the function I use regularly in a package.

At the beginning of my notebook I have a section containing the following stuff.

```
Quit[]

Off[SixJSymbol::tri]

<< fonctionsGenerales`
```

When I run my notebook by evaluation > evaluate notebook, all the functions of my package fonctionsGenerales are unknown by my notebook.

But when I execute line by line this first section, and then I execute the rest of the code normally, everything works fine.

Why by doing "evaluate notebook", my notebook seems to not see the functions in my package ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Evaluate Notebook` all expressions in your notebook are added to the evaluation queue. But the `Quit[]` command by default removes all items from this queue. So nothing gets evaluated.

To change the default behaviour you can use the following command:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" -> False]
```

See also:

[Self-restarting MathKernel - is it possible in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7864643)